# finding and merging back last row in group

Tags: r, dplyr

I can use dplyr to find the last row in a dataset and having a specific value of that row merged back to the whole dataset.

```
data=data.frame(ID=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)), A=seq(1,10))
data=data %>% mutate(last_A=filter(.,row_number()==n())$A)
```

**How do I find the last row of a each group and merge it back to the corrsponding groups. I tried the following which runs with an error:**

```
data=data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(last_A=filter(.,row_number()==n())$A)
```

Comment: Use the `last`-function of `dplyr`: `data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(lastA = last(A))`

Comment: Thanks that solves it for this case. However, is there no way of passing each subgroup on to mutate? Optionally passing a custom function in mutate that takes the whole group as input?

Comment: If it's a `data.table` you can do `data[, lastA := A[.N], by = ID]`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Jaap, you can use `dplyr::last()` to answer your original question.

```r
library(dplyr)

data=data.frame(ID=c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)), A=seq(1,10))

data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(lastA = last(A))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>       ID     A lastA
#>    <dbl> <int> <int>
#>  1  1.00     1     5
#>  2  1.00     2     5
#>  3  1.00     3     5
#>  4  1.00     4     5
#>  5  1.00     5     5
#>  6  2.00     6    10
#>  7  2.00     7    10
#>  8  2.00     8    10
#>  9  2.00     9    10
#> 10  2.00    10    10
```

If you want to do something else with each subgroup, I suggest starting a new question.